# Set-Cookie not accessible through axios or fetch

Tags: vue.js, http, axios, fetch

I am building a web application with a go backend and a vue.js frontend.
I want to do a simple sign in form in which I send the sign in request from a method of my component with Axios (or fetch) and get in response a JSON object of the user and a session token in the cookie to be stored and reused in future requests to the server.

The code of my components method :

```js
class LoginComponent extends Vue {
  sendLogin (): void {
    axios.post<User>('http://192.168.1.227:8080/signin', body)
      .then(res => console.log('Axios Response :', res)
      .catch(err => console.error('Axios Error :', err))
  }
}
```

The part of the code of the go server :
[go API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TKckQ.png)
with the headers :
[go headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IgeqD.png)

the front and backend are on different IP addresses in a local network and they communicate through HTTP.

The problem that I faced is that when receiving the response after the post request to login I don't have access to the cookie that has been set by the server. When I use Axios to analyze the response the cookie isn't in the headers whereas when I look at the network logs in the browser,  the cookie is in the headers but it is not saved and it is not sent when I do another request.

Also, the only header that is visible with Axios is `Content-Type : application/json; charset=UTF-8`

I tried many things to be able to see this cookie but it doesn't work :

- adding `{ withCredentials: true }` to the axios request or `axios.defaults.withCredentials = true` to the axios instance only stops the request because of CORS.
- changing all the Access-Control headers to `"*"` didn't change anything
- using `{ auth: { username: 'foo', password: 'bar' } }` in the axios options instead of the body

The only thing that worked and automatically saved the cookie was to send the request via the attributes of the form html tag, like so :

```html
<form method="POST" action="http://192.168.1.227/signin">
  ...
</form>
```

But this way I am redirected to the JSON response object and not to one of my routes from vue-router and I can't access the User object in my app.

Is there any way that my problem can be solved?

Comment: Sounds like you have a couple of issues, but if the cookie is in the response, your issue is not with Go or the server. Note that Fetch does not send cookies by default: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Comment: yes that's also what I thought, if I get the cookie in the network logs then the server did it's job. But the fact that I can only read one header and not the Set-Cookie from the response of Axios is realy weird, I thought maybe it's the browser that filters the cookie because it's a Cross-Origin request

Comment: You should configure CORS in the right way in order to use cookie. Keep in mind you must use actual domain and not a wildcard. Any combination of `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` and `withCredentials=true` will fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so the comment of [Зелёный](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62575926/set-cookie-not-accessible-through-axios-or-fetch?noredirect=1#comment110666289_62575926) was the answer.

I needed the go server to set `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://192.168.1.218:8080` (the address of the frontend) and then configure axios with `{ withCredentials: true }` to be able to automatically store the cookie. Although I still don't see it when I do a console.log on the axios response, it is successfully stored and reused for each call to the server.